# Is there any way to use for loop to print values in certain range but with a specific order- java

Tags: java

I'm sorry if my question is not very clear because i can't find any other way on how to explain it better.
I want to do something like this by using for loop:

> First iteration : 0 , 1, 2, 3, 4,
>
> Second iteration: 1, 2, 3, 4, 0
>
> Third Iteration : 2, 3, 4, 0, 1
>
> Fourth Itertaion : 3, 4, 0, 1, 2
>
> Fifth iteration : 4, 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> Final Iteration : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

It will print value from 0 to 4 on the first iteration.
And then for the second iteration and the followings the pattern will continue as shown above.
Is it possible to do this using for loop in java?

Comment: Hint 1: Two for loops. Hint 2: `array[(start_position + n) % array.length]`, modulo is your friend.

Comment: You should try to write some code and figure out what's wrong with it first.

Comment: I am lazy: I would duplicate the array and start with an always incerementing index displaying and end after array length. Do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
int iterations = 6;
for (int n = 0; n < iterations; n++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations - 1; i++) {
        int value = (i + n) % (iterations - 1);
        System.out.print(value + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Outputs

```
0 1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 0 
2 3 4 0 1 
3 4 0 1 2 
4 0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4
```

Without more information there's not much else to try. The [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is your friend here, I suggest learning about it.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: thanks, you just saved my life :) the modulo operator is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the array, start by saving the first element and then set every element from the first to the penultimate (that's the next to last) to the next value. Finally, set the last value to the first (that you saved). Something like,

```
private static void rotate(int[] arr) {
    int first = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    arr[arr.length - 1] = first;
}
```

Then, `clone` the original array and iterate with a `do while` loop until your array equals its' original state. Something like,

```
int[] arr = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] original = arr.clone();
do {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    rotate(arr);
} while (!Arrays.equals(arr, original));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
[3, 4, 0, 1, 2]
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Also**, in Java 8+, you might generate your array with

```
int[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 4).toArray();
```

Comment: thanks for the help...very appreciated :)